# Display a table side-by-side dependent on a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a cash book table with the following fields: voucherNo, VoucherType, VoucherDate, Particular, Debit, Credit.

I want to separate records based on voucher type as per the below image. What query should I run or what join should I use use to achieve this view?

> [image]

Comment: You have tagged this question with the names of four different RDBMSs - which one are you actually using? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i m using access 2007 db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  tr.*, tp.*
FROM table_data tr
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table_data tp
     ON (
              tp.VoucherNo# = tr.VoucherNo#
         AND  tp.VoucherType = 'CP'
        )
WHERE    
   tr.VoucherType = 'CR'
;
```

Comment: this query return duplicate result CR voucher type have 3 records and CP voucher type have 2 records this query return 6 records no tr.VoucherNo# = tp.VoucherNo# relation required bcz voucher#3 not available in cp voucher side

Comment: This needs to be a left outer join as there's only on record with `3` and you need a distinct as well.

Comment: ohh yes this is working like charm thank u very much ben and schurik